# Custom Guided Tour for Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

You know how when you first login to Dynamics CRM 2013, you see this pop up with a nice smiling lady and she offers to guide you through how to use the new 2013 version?  Well, a client of ours would like to customize that tour or completely replace that tour with something new and custom.

Has anyone done this before or have any ideas of how this would be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The guided tour is not customizable.

You can create an HTML Webresource to implement your custom tour and add a button inside the command bar to open it.